# Check if any values in array are equal to each other

Tags: php

I'm validating a form that submits up to 3 different id's depending on what the user selects.

I've put them into an array:

```
$submitted_genres = array($_POST['genre1'], $_POST['genre2'], $_POST['genre3']);
```

How I can check to make sure that none of the array values are equal each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `array_unique()` to get an array of all unique values and then compare the size against the original array:

```
if (count(array_unique($submitted_genres)) !== count($submitted_genres)) {
    // there's at least one dupe
}
```